# Android support for TLS 1.1

Tags: encryption, tls, android

Do anybody know from what version of Android did TLS 1.1 started to be supported directly by the OpenSSL version preinstalled in the system?

Answer (score 5):

Using the source listed for the [SSL Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) object in the Android API

## Client Side

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Protocol | Supported API Levels | Enabled by Default (API Levels) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SSLv3    |  1+ (BASE)           |  1+ (BASE)                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1    |  1+ (BASE)           |  1+ (BASE)                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1.1  |  16+(JELLYBEAN)      |  20+(KITKAT_WATCH)              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1.2  |  16+(JELLYBEAN)      |  20+(KITKAT_WATCH)              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Server Side

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Protocol | Supported API Levels | Enabled by Default (API Levels) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SSLv3    |  1+ (BASE)           |  1+ (BASE)                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1    |  1+ (BASE)           |  1+ (BASE)                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1.1  |  16+(JELLYBEAN)      |  16+(JELLYBEAN)                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TLSv1.2  |  16+(JELLYBEAN)      |  16+(JELLYBEAN)                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It should be noted that API 20 is `KITKATW`, or `KITKAT` for wearable devices.  This is not the first `KITKAT` release (that would be API 19).  So for most devices out there the enabled by default for TLSv1.1/1.2 is really for `LOLLIPOP` (API 21) and up.  Here's a quick reference to [API levels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.1 (API 16), according to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your link?  As links tend to break and we'd like the information within the question for easy access.